# XMC1300 boot kit memory corruption

Tags: c, gdb, embedded, cortex-m, infineon

I compiled an example program for XMC1300 boot kit. I was able to do the debugging part - reading memory and registers. This is a simple very basic LED program(worked fine multiple time earlier)

Suddenly I am getting this below error now and I am not able to do anything on the board.

[image]

Please guide me for this issue.

Thanks

I have tried to connect the board with XMC_Flasher and Infineon Memtool 2021 both, but the board is not getting connected.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think this is memory corruption?

The screenshot shows not much useful, but it does show the call stack, and it is clear that it has failed in `SystemInit()` (the startup code called before `main()`). Further, it failed at system_XMC1300.c line 98.

The fact that it has ended up at an invalid memory address suggest some error, stack corruption or stack overflow at start-up.

You have a debugger, use it.  You know that `SystemInit()` was called, so set a breakpoint at the start of that function or possibly at or just before line 98, and step through that code, to discover the point it goes off piste.  Then inspect the state (variables, stack etc.) To see why it fails at that point.

Comment: This is the first window that comes after debug mode. No breakpoint is working here as flash can not be read. I tried to place the breakpoint in startup file which is assembly code. This startup file calls the SystemInit() api.